# Simple counter with a interval using increment

Tags: c++, counter, increment

So i wanted to do a simple counter. I started a version one  by doing a = 18; and b = 100;
With that worked my inkrement. Now i wanted to let the user define start and end. 
So i simply did a little cout / cin dialogue. 
I have no idea why it isn't working as before.

This is the code i'm using:

```
 int a; //start
 a = 0;
 int b; //end
 b = 0;
 cout << "Start eingeben: " << endl; //define start
 cin >> a;
 cout << "Ende eingeben: " << endl; //define end
 cin >> b;
 for(int a ; a <= b; a++){
     cout << a << endl;
 }
```

Comment: There's no actual question here.  In order to construct a *question* that is compatible with StackOverflow, you must: 1) Include code, 2) Include test input data, 3) Include expected output, 4) Include actual output, 5) Explain why you expect the output you expect, 6) Include at least one sentence ending with a question mark (?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for(int a ; a <= b; a++){
```

You define a new `a` variable that shadows the `a` you put a value into. 
Try with:

```
for(; a <= b; a++)
```